# Unreal Engine 4.27 vs Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, package, unreal-engine4

I watched tons of youtube videos, and read documentation, forums but got 0 answers to this problem.
I installed Unreal Engine 4.27 and Android Studio 4.0 according to Unreal documentation:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Mobile/Android/Setup/AndroidStudio/

When I run setupandroid.bat I just got an error:
"The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value. Android Studio not installed, please download Android Studio 3.5.3..." (I already tried that version too but none of it works, I got the same error for that too, so I reinstalled 4.0)
Did anyone get the same error? I'm fighting against this thing for weeks and found nothing on the net...

Answer (score 1):

Open the project in UE4 and manually set the SDK, NDK, and Java paths as described [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Mobile/Android/Setup/AndroidStudio/#manuallytargetingsdkpaths).

Open `Edit > Project Settings`, then `Platforms > Android > Android SDK`
and set the three values.

The type of Android Studio install (single user or all users) does not match the expected value in `setupandroid.bat`.

In any case, manually pointing to the directories will work most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up the system environment variable first before running setupandroid.bat

Tutorial link from Vice versa studio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SY2Za6j7UY

it going to take a bit of time to learn this but in the end, you will succeed